# forcing maven to use local dependency

Tags: maven, apache-spark, dependency-management, spark-graphx

I'm stuck with a problem which may seem silly, but I don't know how to resolve it. I also looked online, but none of the solutions work for me.

I have a spark code which is using the spark graphX module. I need to make changes inside the graphX and force my project to use this modified version of the graphX. In order to do that, I have first taken out the graphx module from spark source code and compiled it independently. Then I specify the dependency in my application pom.xml file, which has the scope of "system". There is my application pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <groupId>edu.asu.gears.examples.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>PageRank</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>"PageRank"</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!--
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  -->
  <properties>
        <java.version>1.8.0</java.version>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <scala.tools.version>2.11</scala.tools.version>
    <spark.version>2.3.2</spark.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <blaze.version>1.0</blaze.version>
    <blaze.base>/home/user/sbiookag/blaze-master</blaze.base>
  </properties>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-graphx_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
                <version>${spark.version}</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${blaze.base}/examples/pageRank/APPs/GraphXFPGAApp/graphx/target/spark-graphx_2.11-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <!--
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>blaze_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
        -->
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I compile my code, it still downloads the graphx dependency and seems like it uses the original jar file during the runtime as well. I really don't know how to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`spark-mllib` contains a dependency on `spark-graphx`. You should exclude it in your pom.xml :

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
  <version>${spark.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-graphx_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```